# Excel show name instead of formula

Tags: excel

I have 1 cell in excel named "CellA".
The cell is filled by "CellA".
When I click on this cell, I would like to see in the formula bar something else than "CellA". Is it possible ?
Thank you !

Comment: I don't think so... but I also don't entirely understand the question. Maybe you could attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This image shows the difference between a Cell Name and the Formula Bar.  The formula bar will show the formula that's actually in the cell, and the Cell Name will always show the cell's name (this is usually the cell address such as `A1` unless you have given the cell a custom name like `CellA` shown here).  The cell itself will show the result of the formula, or simply the text/number that is in the formula bar if it's not actually a formula.

[image]

If you are looking for something else, please clarify your question.

**EDIT:**

Based on OP's comment "What I would like is to see in the cell "Cell A" (or at least any words), but to keep "test" in the formula bar", you can use a custom format to accomplish this.

Right-click the cell -> Select Format Cells -> Select Custom -> Set the Type to be `"CellA";"CellA";"CellA";"CellA"` and click OK.  Now no matter what is in the formula bar, the cell will display "CellA":

[image]

For more information on how custom cell formats work, please see [The Definitive Guide to Custom Number Formats in Excel](http://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/)

Comment: Alternately, you could use a cell comment.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!